# Why hexadecimal representation of floating point numbers so rarely used? (and a few more questions)

Tags: floating-point

Why hexadecimal representation of floating point numbers is so rarely used?

Isn't writing them like `0x0.01` will help avoid some surprises, like 0.01 suddenly becoming `0.010000000000` something?

How long should be the decimal pi to be precise?

There seems to be this instruction FLDPI, which loads pi right into co-processor, why then you have to write pi in code? Is there the same instruction for arm?

Comment: @dwelch so, how to do this? I only managed to write `int main (void){printf("thing in hex: %f\n\n", 0x3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E03707344A4093822299F31D0082EFA98p0 );}`

Comment: no point answering that question again here, just look at the existing answers.

Comment: which one, i don't understand

Comment: Short answer : because we don't have 16 fingers :P

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq thank you for your answers, you are awesome! On my system c99 still forces me to add 0x and p0 to constants, don't know why. Are you sure double needs 16 numbers after the dot, and not 16 in total? If you'd write your answers as separate posts, i'd upvote them.

Comment: Your question is not a very good match for the StackOverflow format (asking several sub-questions in one question is confusing, and the first sub-question is a question of preference) so your question may get closed. This is why I don't write an answer for it. But I am glad if my comments help anyway.

Comment: Since you asked for it and it dis not look like this question was going to be closed, I moved my comments to an answer. I was the only way to fix some typos in what I had typed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, about the "how long should π be" question. These functions:

```
int main (void){printf("%.80f\n\n", 0x3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E03707344A4093822299F31D0082EFA98p0 );}
int main (void){printf("%.80f\n\n", 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459 );}
int main (void){printf("%.80f\n\n", 3.141592653589793 );}
```

print exactly the same number:

```
3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500000000000000000000000000000000
```

if it becomes any shorter, result will differ.

Answer (score 1):

I use C99's hexadecimal notation for floats all the time, both for input and for output.

Using the decimal format D.DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEXXX (sixteen digits after the decimal dot) guarantees that the notation uniquely identifies any `double`, including the double closest to π.

A language like C is intended to be portable and shouldn't depend on what one particular instruction set can do. The old 80-bit floating-point instructions are quite obsolete too, although they are still useful for programs that explicitly compute with 80-bit `long double`. 
In the special case of π, `3.141592653589793` is the minimal decimal representation to get the right `double`.
Also, note that the compiler can always generate the instruction `FLDPI` when the constant in the program is exactly the constant that would be loaded by the instruction. However, again, the 80-bit FPU is obsolete and should only be used by a modern compiler for long double computations. After testing, neither GCC nor Clang generate the `FLDPI` instruction, even when moving `0x3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E03707344` to a `long double`. Lame… I almost feel like filling out a bug report.

The `0x` and `p` markers are necessary to avoid ambiguities with integer notations. In hexadecimal, it's very simple: each hexadecimal digits represents 4 bits and a normal double has the form 1.<52 binary digits>. Therefore, exactly 13 hexadecimal digits after `1.` are significant. In decimal it is up to 16 digits that are necessary to identify a `double`. To observe this yourself, execute:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
…
printf("%.16e\n%.16e\n", 1.0, nextafter(1.0, 2.0));
```

to see that fewer digits would cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

consider your experience in daily life: do you handle and encounter real numbers in decimal or specified to any other radix ?

you'd still be up to surprises since rounding and approximation errors in computing with floating point values will occur anyway.

Comment: but at least addition and multiplication will work ok most of the time

Comment: arithmetic operations will fail and succeed to the same extent unless you change the internal representation. of course, in using a binary/hex representation at the surface you avoid conversion errors. however, the data you feed your fp algorithm with are determined by factors external to your code. so while you do not suffer from conversion errors you reintroduce imprecision by not being able to express the data you have to compute on in the format in the first place.

Comment: hm... It's not a problem if i generate all the data myself, and don't use textual representation anywhere exept of user output. Maybe i store values in some binary format without any conversion at all.

Comment: “you'd still be up to surprises since rounding and approximation errors in computing with floating point values will occur anyway” it a terrible way to look at it. By writing in hexadecimal, it becomes possible to make it clear that some approximations do not occur either in the representation of the constant or in the subsequent computations. Take the line `C=0x8000001p0;` on http://proval.lri.fr/gallery/Dekker.en.html for instance.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: you are right as far as fp constants in source code are concerned which can be represented exactly in the fp format supported by the machine. however the decimal expansion of these constants can also be represented exactly which does not necessarily hold the other way round. in the example you gave the hex notation of the constant conveys meaning that will be lost in base 10 and if the OP had precisely these cases in mind, my argument does not apply.

Comment: The first hexadecimal digits of π are tattooed on my forearm (no, they aren't, but I seriously considered the possibility).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: that would make a premium geek shirt overprint ...